# NumberFormatException when trying to perform sort() or orderBy() on a dataframe in spark using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame **df** that has 3 columns (as included in the image).
[data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajOwn.jpg)
when i execute

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
df.sort($"count".desc)
```

or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.orderBy(desc("count"))
```

it appears to be done successfully but when i try to `show()` or `collect()`, I get the following error-

> 18/07/06 05:06:56, 594 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: show at :52
>   18/07/06 05:06:56, 596 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 6 (show at :52) with 2 output partitions
>   18/07/06 05:06:56, 596 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 6 (show at :52)
>   18/07/06 05:06:56, 596 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
>   18/07/06 05:06:56, 596 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
>   18/07/06 05:06:56, 596 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 6 (MapPartitionsRDD[20] at show at :52), which has no missing parents
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   Lost task 1.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 11, localhost): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Sint Eustatius"
>           at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
>           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:229)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:31)
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .

and so on.

only included some lines because its too big. is there any other way to sort this df based on the column -count???

### edit 1

this is the result on displaying the dataframe.
[df.show()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSgxk.jpg)

### edit 2

when i try to execute using *sqlContext*, in the following way -

```
val df1=sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from df  order by count desc").collect()
```

I get table not found error. how should I convert df into a table?

Comment: df.orderBy(desc("count"))  It looks fine and It must work. there is some other problem.

Comment: i also tried sorting using sqlContext, it returns table not found error

Comment: Before doing this -  val df1=sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from df order by count desc") You have to do  df.registerAsTempTable("table") then  val df1=sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from table order by count desc") and then df1.show

Comment: In case of dataframe you need not to use collect at all

Comment: Read the count column as string and then use sql cast function to typecast it to int. For string values, you would get null value. You can coalesce this to whatever value you want

Comment: @candyculen is that true that the data frame called 'df' was constructed from many others source files/ dataframes. For example, u have 2 other dataframes called: df1 & df2. And you construct 'df' by union df1 and df2.

Answer (score 1):

Understand that Spark won't compute any of the code until you apply an action on a dataFrame/RDD; in another words RDDs/DFs are lazily evaluated. [Read Spark Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations)

Now in your case `orderBy` and `sort` are transformations and spark won't execute any code until you have a transformation, and the `show` and `collect` are actions which tells the spark to `orderBy` or `sort` and to get the result.

The error that you have now is due to a string `Sint Eustatius` in the column  `count` which is a string type and string type cannot be casted into Integer.

Validate your data once and make sure you have only Integer values in the column `count`, this should solve your issue.

Comment: val schema = new StructType().add(StructField("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME",StringType,true)).add(StructField("ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME",StringType,true)).add(StructField("count",IntegerType,true))

Comment: this is the line where i create schema for the csv file that i want to load into df. IntegerType is not defining the data type for count?

Comment: Even if you apply a schema, the schema is validated only during the runtime, which is when you apply a action over the dataframe or RDD.

Comment: so can i typecast a single column separately? what should be done?

Comment: scala> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: integer (nullable = true)

Comment: the column data type is integer only

Answer (score 0):

Here is my dataframe and queries that I wrote and working fine.

```
val sparkSession=SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("LearnScala").getOrCreate()
val data = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row(1, "A", "B"), Row(2, "A", "B")))
val schema = StructType(Array( StructField("col1", IntegerType, false),StructField("col2", StringType, false), StructField("col3", StringType, false)))
val df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data, schema)

//df.show
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   A|   B|
|   2|   A|   B|
+----+----+----+

df.orderBy(desc("col1")).show
df.sort(df.col("col1").desc).show

//Above both expressions produces the same output like below
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   2|   A|   B|
|   1|   A|   B|
+----+----+----+
```